# Cant find file with glob.glob if name as paired brackets

Tags: python-3.x

edit:
my previous tests shows that glob.glob("file[2]*.*") is empty but not glob.glob("file[2*.*")

I will try to be concrete ...

I have files in a directory:

```
john.txt
john-ok.asc
alice[2].txt
alice[2]-ok.asc
doe(3].txt
doe(3]-ok.zza
donald.txt
```

I want to check for every file.ext if file-ok.* exist but it doesn't works if file contains paired brackets []

```
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import os

################################## deb get_info #############################################
def get_info(file):
    file_name_we = Path(file).stem            # le nom du ficher sans extension
    file_path = os.path.dirname(file)         # le chemin du fichier
    file_ok = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path, file_name_we) + '-ok.*')    
    if file_ok == []:
        print (file, "file as no ok")
    else:
        print (file, "file as ok")
################################## fin get_info #############################################
############################## Main ######################################
filelist = glob.glob("z:/t/**/*.txt", recursive=True)
for file in filelist:
    get_info(file)
```

here is the result

```
z:/t\alice[2].txt file as no ok
z:/t\doe(3].txt file as ok
z:/t\donald.txt file as no ok
z:/t\john.txt file as ok
```

alice[2] should have ok

if you have any idea ? 
thanks in advance ;)

Comment: read about `glob`. It is not returning a list as you think. It returns a 3-tuple of `(root, sub_directories, files)`

Comment: thank you, but how do you explain it works for all files except those with [] in it (btw documentation talk about a list)

Comment: I haven't got a clue TBH... I would say add some prints and see what you're working with... for example `print(file)` at the start of `get_info`

Comment: I have the correct path : file :  z:/t\alice[2].txt  -  file :  z:/t\doe(3].txt  -  file :  z:/t\donald.txt  - file :  z:/t\john.txt as the result show

Comment: so add prints of `file_ok` and the others

Comment: I did, just wanted to show clean code. I can say with other tests that glob.glob("file[2]*.*") is empty but not glob.glob("file[2*.*")

Comment: `[ ]` are special in `glob`, just like `*`. `file[2]` is equivalent to `file2`.

Comment: ok, thank you, so with  file_ok = glob.glob((os.path.join(file_path, file_name_we) + '-ok.*').replace('[', '[[]'))  it works now

Answer (score 0):

thanks melpomene ;)

glob special characters & wildcards

```
*   any characters  *.txt matches all files with the txt extension
?   any one character   ??? matches files with 3 characters long
[]  any character listed in the brackets    [ABC]* matches files starting with A,B or C
[..]    any character in the range listed in brackets   [A..Z]* matches files starting with capital letters
[!]     any character listed in the brackets    [!ABC]* matches files that do not start with A,B or C
```

so the use of glob.glob1 or .replace('[', '[[]') help me to continue ;)